# Массив заполняется мусором

Tags: c, файлы, qtcreator, динамические-массивы

Нужно заполнить динамический двумерный массив с файла, затем показать его на экране. В файле первые две строки - количество строк и столбцов массива, дальше сам массив.

Проблема в том, что массив заполняется мусором. Раньше функция чтения с файла принимала только указатель на массив, и вывод происходил в той же функции.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
void readFile(double *arr, int *rw, int *cl)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("array.txt", "rt");

    if(file != NULL){
        fscanf(file, "%d%d", rw, cl);
        arr = (double*)malloc((*rw) * (*cl) * sizeof(double));

        for(int i = 0; i < *rw; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < *cl; j++){
                fscanf(file, "%lf", (arr + i*(*cl) + j));
            }
        }

}
    else printf("Ошибка ввода.\n");
    fclose(file);
}
void showArray(double *arr, int rw, int cl)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rw; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cl; j++){
            printf("%g\t", *(arr + i*cl + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main()
{
    double *array;
    int row = 0, column = 0;
    readFile(array, &row, &column);
    showArray(array, row, column);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не "заполняется мусором". Функция `readFile` никак не возвращает указатель на выделенный массив в вызывающий код. Указатель `array` как был мусором в `main`, так и остался указывать "в никуда".

Что характерно, по тому, как вы передаете в функцию `readFile` переменные `row` и `column` видно, что суть проблемы вы прекрасно понимаете, т.е. понимаете, что переменные нужно передавать "по указателю". Так почему с `array` вы не приняли никаких мер для того, чтобы и его тоже передавать правильно?

Comment: Всё-таки я не совсем понимаю, как правильно передавать. Разве я также не передаю указатель на массив?

Comment: @Александр Ерохин: Какой такой "указатель на массив"? Изначально у вас нет никакого массива. Поэтому и передавать указатель на него вы никак никуда не можете. Вы передаете указатель `array` в функцию и хотите, чтобы его значение там поменялось и вернулось в вызывающий код? Это значит, что вам надо передавать `&array`, так же, как и с другими переменными. То есть указатель на указатель.